# Using a space and slash with New-Item

Tags: powershell, registry, whitespace, quoting

So I have to add this registry entry using PowerShell and sadly it has a space and a `/` in it. I'd like to know what the syntax is for adding this kind of entry or a new method because I'm unable to find a good answer. To be clear this needs to create a key called `RC4 128/128` under the ciphers folder.

`New-Item -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Ciphers" -Name RC4 128/128`

This is the error I got below:

> New-Item : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '128/128'.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + New-Item -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProvid ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-Item], ParameterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand

Comment: Have you tried quoting? `-Name "RC4 128/128"`

Comment: @lit This is one of the things powershell can't understand.  Every case I've seen trying to work with SCHANNEL falls back to using the .NET classes to manipulate that registry path.  I think it's due to its path interpretation and being nice in accepting any slash direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a Powershell issue, but it's an issue with the way the `New-Item` cmdlet is written.

Here's how you do it though:

`([Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey([Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive]::LocalMachine, $env:COMPUTERNAME)).CreateSubKey('SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Ciphers\RC4 128/128')`

[Credit: u/bhudlemeyer from reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/34kvyv/how_do_you_escape_in_powershell/)

It's very strange that they require you to create a key path with a space and slash because even regedit doesn't allow that.

Comment: thank you! it worked and then i used `Set-ItemProperty` to add the enabled dword and its good now.